# craco configuration with mode attribute

Tags: webpack, craco

I was going through the CRACO documentation and it all looks very confusing.
But my basic question was if there is any relevance to the "mode" attribute in craco.config.js OR it is a non-existent property?

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production', //'development'
  webpack: {}
}
```